# "include": [] not working in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, tsc, tsconfig

I am using tsconfig.json to compile my project built in typescript 
the tsc version is 1.8.10 and this is my tsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "listFiles": true,
    "outFile": "../outputs/output.js"
  },
  "include": [
    "../src/*.ts",
    "../app/*.ts"
  ],

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

The problem here is irrespective of anything i mention in "include" all the ts files from root->parent directory are compiled. I only want `ts` files in app and source folders to be compiled. I understand that I can keep the rest of folders I don't need in "exclude". But what I don't is, Why are ts files not mentioned in "include" getting picked up?

2.)In my project I am planning to have multiple tsconfig.json files and I need all the ts files in parent directory be compiled first before the one's in root. Is there any way I can mention the order of compilation?

Comment: [Glob support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#glob-support-in-tsconfigjson) was not added until TypeScript 2.0, so the wildcards in your configuration will not be behaving the way you might expect.

Comment: Also, make sure just run `tsc` as if you run tsc with a file glob it will overlook your tsconfig.